# Interworking MPI between Windows and Linux

Tags: mpi, heterogeneous, infiniband

I have several Windows box and Linux box interconnected with Infiniband, and I need to run MPI jobs in both environment, does anyone know what's the best way to interwork them ?

Currently, I am considering using the beta release of windows binary of open MPI. Maybe I need to add additional things into my hpc sw stack ? Or should I just forget about MPI and directly code in a lower layer for the getting the windows part to work, since there are few jobs that needs windows anyway.

Any idea is appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I dig through some of forums and find that

openMPI currently does not support interworking of task spawning between windows and linux systems, however MpiCh2 seems to be capable of interworking task spawning. For sending and receiving messages using MPI send, I will need to investigate more

Comment: Keep in mind that MPICH2 does not have InfiniBand support, though you could probably get it to run with IPoIB.  This may be quite slow compared to native IB.  MVAPICH2 would provide native IB support, but I have no idea whether interop between Windows and Linux is possible with it.